# How do i test if my hamachi minecraft server is working and able to be accsessed from outside connections?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I Cant tell if my hamachi server is able to be accessed from outside connections scince hamachi ips are diffrent then your ip and you cant change your ip on canyouseeme.org or other sites like that

Comment: If Hamachi hasn't changed, then it still works as a VPN.  Outside connections will not be able to see the server unless they also have Hamachi.  As for testing if outside connections work, that's a different issue.  What do you have access to (a server or remote desktop)?

Comment: Hamachi creates a VPN that only people with the right login details can access. If you give said login details to others, then they can access your network regardless of port forwarding and accepting external connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running hamachi off the computer you're running the client and server on, it's pretty simple. Make sure the other person has hamachi and try to ping each other through it by right clicking their name. If they can ping you and you can ping them, there should be no connection issues and you're good to go.